# what is boost.asio.detail.read_op means?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I read asio in boost.1.50 source code, what is means of the methond?

```
void operator()(const boost::system::error_code& ec,
    std::size_t bytes_transferred, int start = 0)
{
  switch (start)
  {
    case 1:
    buffers_.prepare(this->check_for_completion(ec, total_transferred_));
    for (;;)
    {
      stream_.async_read_some(buffers_,
          BOOST_ASIO_MOVE_CAST(read_op)(*this));
      return; default:
      total_transferred_ += bytes_transferred;
      buffers_.consume(bytes_transferred);
      buffers_.prepare(this->check_for_completion(ec, total_transferred_));
      if ((!ec && bytes_transferred == 0)
          || buffers_.begin() == buffers_.end())
        break;
    }

    handler_(ec, static_cast<const std::size_t&>(total_transferred_));
  }
}
```

The code is pick up fron boost_1_50_0\boost\asio\impl\read.hpp.
switch case style looks like very strange, "return;default:"???

Answer (score 1):

This is a functor that manages a composed read operation.

When invoked for the first time (`start == 1`), it prepares the buffer, issues the first read, passing itself as the completion handler, and returns.

Now, each time being invoked as a completion handler, it jumps directly to `default` label and updates the buffer and the internal counters, and issues another read, if needed.

Actually, it was possible to split this operator into 2 separate ones: one for the initial read, and the other for the subsequent calls. But maybe such an approach would generate more code, and thus was rejected by the library author.

Comment: Thanks, I thought the "default" should be in new case label.Maybe i don't understand the switch-case grammar

Comment: @billow `default` itself is a case "label". But the standard doesn't disallow to put it inside `for` loop. Try the following code: #include <iostream>

int main()
{
 int i = 2;
 switch(i)
 {
 case 1:
  std::cout << 1;
  for (;;)
  {
   default:
   std::cout << 2;
  }
 };
}